# python3 how to use os.scandir for each type of file inside a class

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to improve my OOP in python,

I wanted to add many useful functions, 
as a start I tried listing

mp3, mp4, Images, and to show a list of the non supported extensions and then returning to show and work with in my main project

```
import os

class Functions(object):

    # templates/video/vids
    def scan_dir(self, this_dir="/home/X/Videos", videos=[], images=[], audio=[], folder=[], denied=[]):
        # EXTENSIONS #
        ##############
        self.videos = videos
        self.images = images
        self.audio  = audio
        self.folder = folder
        self.denied = denied


        for files in os.scandir(this_dir):
            # for files in this_dir:
            #
                ## VIDEOS
                ###########
                if files[:3] == "mp4" or files[:3] == "MP4" or files[:3] == "FLV" or files[:3] == "flv" :
                    videos.append(files)

                ## IMAGES
                ###########
                elif files[:3] == "PNG" or files[:3] == "png" or files[:3] == "JPG" or files[:3] == "jpg" :
                    images.append(files)

                ## AUDIO
                ###########
                elif files[:3] == "mp3" or files[:3] == "MP3" or files[:3] == "wav" or files[:3] == "WAV" :
                        audio.append(files)

                ## FOLDER
                ###########
                elif files.name.startswith('.'):
                        folder.append(files)

                ## DENIED
                ###########
                else:
                    denied.append(files)

                VIDSTR = ' '.join(videos)
                IMGSTR = ' '.join(images)
                AUDSTR = ' '.join(audio)
                FOLSTR = ' '.join(folder)
                DENSTR = ' '.join(denied)

                sorted_files = [VIDSTR, IMGSTR, AUDSTR, FOLSTR, DENSTR]


        return sorted_files
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few changes you could make.

You could use a factory function to classify files based on their extension or some other pattern.  Also take advantage of `defaultdict` and append to it based on each file's classification.

From your code, its unclear whether you actually want to return the file name as a `str`, which would be `os.DirEntry.name`, or just the object, `os.DirEntry`, which is what you can pass to `classify()` here.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import os

def classify(file: os.DirEntry) -> int:
    file = file.name.lower()
    if file.endswith(('.mp4', '.flv')):
        return 0
    elif file.endswith(('.png', '.jpg')):
        return 1
    elif file.endswith(('.mp3', '.wav')):
        return 2
    elif file.startswith('.'):
        return 3
    else:
        return 4

class Functions(object):
    def __init__(self, this_dir="/home/X/Videos"):
        self.this_dir = this_dir
        self.allfiles = defaultdict(list)

    def scan_dir(self) -> defaultdict:
        for file in os.scandir(self.this_dir):
            self.allfiles[classify(file)].append(file)
        return self.allfiles
```

Example:

```
>>> f = Functions(this_dir='/Users/brad/Downloads/media/')
>>> f.scan_dir()
defaultdict(list,
            {0: [<DirEntry 'movie2.mp4'>, <DirEntry 'movie.mp4'>],
             1: [<DirEntry 'pic.png'>],
             2: [<DirEntry 'music.wav'>, <DirEntry 'music2.mp3'>],
             3: [<DirEntry '.hidden'>, <DirEntry '.DS_Store'>]})
```

Comment: is it possible to be done without collections library?
thank you so much

Comment: Sure, initialize a dictionary of empty lists with keys 0 thru 4.